# HTML: What does "elements stacked up on top of one another"

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML & CSS. I am not able to comprehend the stacking of HTML elements. It confusing me a lot. I am going through [layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction) from  Mozilla CSS Guide. It has following piece of code.

```html
<p>I love my cat.</p>

<ul>
  <li>Buy cat food</li>
  <li>Exercise</li>
  <li>Cheer up friend</li>
</ul>

<p>The end!</p>
```

It says:

> HTML is displayed in the exact order in which it
>   appears in the source code, with elements stacked up on top of one
>   another — the first paragraph, followed by the unordered list,
>   followed by the second paragraph.

I don't understand the stacked top of one another part. They are lying below one another. And they are added to the bottom of the stack not on the top. I am not able to visualize. Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the screen, the UL is on top of the "The end" and "I love my cat" is on top of the UL - it is not a great description I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On top" does not refer to the z- but to the y-Axis here. This just means that the elements that appear in the HTML first will be on the site first, too (top-to-bottom).

For example:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<img alt="Random image" src="..."></img>
<div>Hello 2</div>
```

Will render

```
Hello
Image
Hello 2
```

Comment: Ah! It was axis part which was confusing me. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

This means that the flow of HTML elements in the actual that page you see appear in the exact same order that it appears in the code. In your example,  "I love my cat" is on top of the `ul` list which is on top of "The end".